# Stop navigation if another link is clicked Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form in angular and when it is submitted, there is a redirection to homepage after X seconds.

Here is the service containing the redirection method:

```
export class RouterService {
  private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }

  redirectToHome() {
    timer(REDIRECT_TIMEOUT_MS)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
  }
}
```

Here is the submit method:

```
    this.missionService
      .createMission(mission)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'success',
            summary: 'Mission created successfully',
            detail: '',
            life: 5000,
          });
          this.routerService.redirectToHome();
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'error',
            summary: error.error.reason,
            detail: error.error.message,
            life: 5000,
          });
        },
      });
```

I'd like to know how can I stop redirectToHome() if suppose an user click somewhere else in the menu before x seconds have elapsed.

Comment: Your `RouterService` can hold an extra property `preventNavigation = false`, which you can set to `true` whenever the user clicks one of the menu links. Inside of the `subscribe` you can do `if(this.preventNavigation) { this.preventNavigation = false; return; }`.

Comment: @MikeS. that's very un-reactive-like.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It's one way to do it that came to my mind, so why not suggest it? Hence it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Suggesting bad practices is not what I like to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add an cancelNavigation subject in your service which would cancel navigation if called.

```
public cancelNavigation$ = new Subject<void>();

redirectToHome() {
    timer(REDIRECT_TIMEOUT_MS)
      .pipe(
           takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
           takeUntil(this.cancelNavigation$)
      )
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
  }
```